# How can I downcast a non-'static object?

Tags: rust

```
use std::any::Any;

trait Animal {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
}

struct Dog { }
impl Dog {
    fn yell(&self) {
        println!("Wouaf !")
    }
}
impl Animal for Dog {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        self
    }
}
fn main() {
    let dog = Dog { };
    let mut animals = Vec::new() as Vec<&dyn Animal>;
    animals.push(&dog);
    let animal = animals.get_mut(0).unwrap();
    animal.as_any().downcast_ref::<Dog>().unwrap().yell();
}
```

This code compiles great. From what I've read, `as_any()` is a good way to downcast.

Now I add a field `Collar` to my struct `Dog` which will be a reference. I add a lifetime on my struct `Dog` to prevent dangling references with `Collar`.

```
use std::any::Any;

...
struct Collar {
    name: String
}
struct Dog<'a> {
    collar: &'a Collar
}
impl <'a> Dog<'a> {
    fn yell(&self) {
        println!("{}: Wouaf !", self.collar.name)
    }
}
fn main() {
    let collar = Collar { name: String::from("Snoopy !!") };
    ...
}
```

The code does not compile anymore. From what I understand `Any` come with static lifetime, but I have defined a `'a` lifetime which is incompatible. In this case, how can I solve the issue in order to achieve the downcast of `Animal` to `Dog`?

Comment: Non-`'static` `Any` is very problematic. See https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1849-non-static-type-id.html, https://users.rust-lang.org/t/downcasting-non-static-types/19044, https://docs.rs/better_any/latest/better_any/.