# Is there a workaround for the fact that TypeId only works for 'static types?

Tags: rust, ffi

I am giving C++ a `Box` containing a trait object, and then when I get that `Box<dyn Trait>` back from C++, I want to try to downcast it into a concrete type. However, I can't do it safely because the types I'm using are not (and cannot be) `'static`, so I can't use `Any::downcast_ref`. Is there another way to assert that the cast that I'm doing is valid (ex.: is there a hack I can use to generate something like a `TypeId` that ignores lifetime parameters)?

Comment: If it ignores lifetimes, doesn't that immediately mean your code is at risk of being unsafe? It seems like you'll need to add real code demonstrating how the lifetimes come into play for anyone here to be able to suggest potential alternatives.

Comment: There is no way to assert that a certain lifetime is valid at runtime, you'd have to verify the lifetime in association with an object that it is bound to (by some other means)

Comment: See [How can I downcast a non-'static object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70534971/how-can-i-downcast-a-non-static-object#comment124684609_70534971)